# How to get rdp client ip in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, rdp

I want to find client address and PORT in remote desktop connection.
I want to use windows API and c++ programing in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window has a IP tables that have all connected IP, that is in the IphlpAPI.
this is a link for that:(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923578.aspx)